# How to run .exe fiile automatically at scheduled time even if system is turned off?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio

I am working on python project, where at particular time (8 pm) a random number will be displayed. I have converted .py file to .exe using pyinstaller. Now, I want my .exe file to run automatically and display the number, even if I won't open .exe file at 8pm.

Comment: You can try using `cron`, `schedule`, or a daemon to run it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're referring to `.exe` I assume you're on Windows.
You should use the Task Scheduler in Windows to schedule your application to run.

For that you could run it with full path to your `python.exe` with the `.py` file as parameter, so conferting to `.exe` isn't really necessary.

To automagically run this on time when the system is switched off, you will need to check the BIOS settings of your PC at startup to see if you can make the computer switch on all by itself at a certain time. Make sure to set this automatic power on a few minutes before the scheduled task to allow Windows to start up first.